# Python Beautiful soup Retrieving html content inside and element id

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape an HTML page

```
 productsoup = BeautifulSoup(productdriver.page_source,"lxml");
```

This python script gives the html that contains the element id section below

```html
<div style="padding-top: 10px;" id="government_funding">
    <h2>Sampling of Recent Funding Actions/Set Asides</h2>
    <p style="font-style: italic; font-size: .8em;">In order by amount of set aside monies.</p>
    <ul>
        <li><span style="color: green;">$14,450</span> - Thursday the 17th of August 2017<br><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;">National Institutes Of Health</span> <br> NATIONAL INSTITUTES OF HEALTH NICHD<br>AVANTI POLAR LIPIDS:1109394 [17-010744]
            <hr>
        </li>
        <li><span style="color: green;">$5,455</span> - Thursday the 31st of August 2017<br><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;">National Institutes Of Health</span> <br> NATIONAL INSTITUTES OF HEALTH NICHD<br>AVANTI POLAR LIPIDS:1109394 [17-004567]
            <hr>
        </li>
        <li><span style="color: green;">$5,005</span> - Tuesday the 8th of August 2017<br><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;">National Institutes Of Health</span> <br> NATIONAL INSTITUTES OF HEALTH NIAID<br>CUSTOM LIPID SYNTHESIS (24:0-10:0 PE) 100 MG PACKAGED IN 10-10MG VIALS POWDER PER QUOTE #DQ-000665
            <hr>
        </li>
        <li><span style="color: green;">$5,005</span> - Thursday the 17th of August 2017<br><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;">National Institutes Of Health</span> <br> NATIONAL INSTITUTES OF HEALTH NIAID<br>CUSTOM LIPID SYNTHESIS (24:0-10:0 PE) 100 MG PACKAGED IN 10-10MG VIALS POWDER PER QUOTE #DQ-000665
            <hr>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this is just a section of the html, this section is identified by id="government_funding". for each of the li in id="goverment_funding" print price, date, agency. So the output for one the li would be

price = $14,450

Date = 17th of August 2017

Agency = National Institutes Of Health

SubAgency = NATIONAL INSTITUTES OF HEALTH NICHD

How could I code the output above?

the link to the data source is this 
https://www.collierreporting.com/company/avanti-polar-lipids-inc-alabaster-al

Comment: Do you have a link to the data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the `li` tags and the subsequent `span` values, and use `re.findall` to access the data:

```
import re
def all_data(d):
  a, b = [i.text for i in d.find_all('span')]
  return [a, *re.findall('\w+\sthe\s\w+\sof\s\w+\s\d+', d.text), b]

results = [all_data(b) for b in productsoup.find('div', {'id':'government_funding'}).find_all('li')]
```

Output:

```
[['$14,450', 'Thursday the 17th of August 2017', 'National Institutes Of Health'], ['$5,455', 'Thursday the 31st of August 2017', 'National Institutes Of Health'], ['$5,005', 'Tuesday the 8th of August 2017', 'National Institutes Of Health'], ['$5,005', 'Thursday the 17th of August 2017', 'National Institutes Of Health']]
```

Comment: There are other <li> in the html, is the a way narrow it down to <li> inside id="goverment_funding"

Comment: @learner101 Please see my recent edit. The `"government_funding"` `div` object can be used.

Comment: can you please explain the code, especially the return statement. I also discover that the subAgency is not being printed out